# phpword Table vmerge and gridspan

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpword

I'm trying to create a table with `PHPWord`, the table should be like this:
some rows that contain 2 cells, and some rows that contain 4 cells

```
------------------------
|     |                | 
|-----------------------
|     |                |
------------------------
|     |     |     |    |                
|-----------------------
```

this is a portion of my code

```
    $table->addRow(200);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleTitleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);
    $table->addCell(15000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('textVULN'), $fontTitle);

    $table->addRow(600);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleTitleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('Référence'), $fontTitle);
    $table->addCell(15000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars(' text'), $fontStyle);

    $table->addRow(600);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleTitleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);
    $table->addCell(15000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('constats ici'), $fontStyle);

    $table->addRow(600);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleTitleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);
    $table->addCell(15000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontStyle);
    //elements impactés
    $table->addRow(600);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleTitleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('Eléments impactés'), $fontTitle);
    $table->addCell(15000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('Les elements ici'), $fontStyle);


    $table->addRow(600);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleTitleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);
    $table->addCell(15000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontStyle);


    $table->addRow(600);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleTitleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontStyle);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleTitleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);
    $table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontStyle);
```

and thats what i get:

```
----------------------
|     |              | 
|---------------------------------
|     |              |     |     |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: found it, i had to add array('gridSpan' => 3) ($table->addCell(15000, array('gridSpan' => 3))->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);)

Comment: Write an answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

found it, i had to add `'gridSpan' => 3` in cell styling array to merge cell

> $table->addCell(15000, $cellStylingArray)->addText($text, $textStylingArray);

```
$table->addCell(15000, array('gridSpan' => 3))->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);
```